# Undo/Redo for Listview LabelEdit and Checkbox selection

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listview, undo

I've done this usercontrol with an ***UndoRedo Manager*** integrated with the help of some people.

At the moment it only can undo/redo when you add or delete an item and that's all, but I would like to implement LabelEdit undo/redo and checkbox undo/redo.

PS: Notice that the `Listview_Action` expects an `ListviewItem`

Here is the Undo/Redo manager Class, is not the full code but just the necessary.

What changes I need to perform in this Class to add the improvements that I need?

Please I will appreciate it if someone could show me a full code example.

```
Public Class myListView : Inherits ListView

    Public Event ItemAdded As EventHandler(Of ItemAddedEventArgs)
    Public Class ItemAddedEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
        Property Item As ListViewItem
    End Class

    Public Event ItemRemoved As EventHandler(Of ItemRemovedEventArgs)
    Public Class ItemRemovedEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
        Property Item As ListViewItem
    End Class

#Region " Undo/Redo Manager "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Enable or disble the Undo/Redo monitoring.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property Enable_UndoRedo_Manager As Boolean = False

    ' Stacks to store Undo/Redo actions.
    Private Property Undostack As New Stack(Of ListView_Action)
    Private Property Redostack As New Stack(Of ListView_Action)

    ' Flags to check if it is doing a Undo/Redo operation.
    Private IsDoingUndo As Boolean = False
    Private IsDoingRedo As Boolean = False

    ' Delegate to Add an Item for Undo/Redo operations.
    Private Delegate Sub AddDelegate(item As ListViewItem)

    ' Delegate to Remove an Item for Undo/Redo operations.
    Private Delegate Sub RemoveDelegate(item As ListViewItem)

    ' The Undo/Redo action.
    Private action As ListView_Action = Nothing

    ' The operation.
    Public Enum Operation As Short
        Undo = 0
        Redo = 1
    End Enum

    ' The method for the Undo/Redo operation.
    Public Enum Method As Short
        Add = 0
        Remove = 1
    End Enum

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a Undo/Redo Action.
    ''' </summary>
    Class ListView_Action

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Names the Undo/Redo Action.
        ''' </summary>
        Property Name As String

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Points to a method to excecute.
        ''' </summary>
        Property Operation As [Delegate]

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Method of the Undo/Redo operation.
        ''' </summary>
        Property Method As Method

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Data Array for the method to excecute.
        ''' </summary>
        Property Data As ListViewItem

    End Class

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This event is raised after an Undo/Redo action is performed.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Event UndoRedo_IsPerformed As EventHandler(Of UndoneRedoneEventArgs)
    Public Class UndoneRedoneEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
        Property Operation As Operation
        Property Method As Method
        Property Item As ListViewItem
        Property UndoStack As Stack(Of ListView_Action)
        Property RedoStack As Stack(Of ListView_Action)
    End Class

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This event is raised when Undo/Redo Stack size changed.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Event UndoRedo_StackSizeChanged As EventHandler(Of StackSizeChangedEventArgs)
    Public Class StackSizeChangedEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
        Property UndoStack As Stack(Of ListView_Action)
        Property RedoStack As Stack(Of ListView_Action)
        Property UndoStackIsEmpty As Boolean
        Property RedoStackIsEmpty As Boolean
    End Class

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Undo the last action.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Undo()

        If Me.Undostack.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' Nothing to Undo.

        Me.IsDoingUndo = True
        Me.action = Me.Undostack.Pop ' Get the Action from the Stack and remove it.
        Me.action.Operation.DynamicInvoke(Me.action.Data) ' Invoke the undo Action.
        Me.IsDoingUndo = False

        Raise_UndoRedo_IsPerformed(Operation.Undo, Me.action.Method, Me.action.Data)

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Redo the last action.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Redo()

        If Me.Redostack.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' Nothing to Redo.

        Me.IsDoingRedo = True
        Me.action = Me.Redostack.Pop() ' Get the Action from the Stack and remove it.
        Me.action.Operation.DynamicInvoke(Me.action.Data) ' Invoke the redo Action.
        Me.IsDoingRedo = False

        Raise_UndoRedo_IsPerformed(Operation.Redo, Me.action.Method, Me.action.Data)

    End Sub

    ' Reverses an Undo/Redo action
    Private Function GetReverseAction(ByVal e As UndoneRedoneEventArgs) As ListView_Action

        Me.action = New ListView_Action

        Me.action.Name = e.Item.Text
        Me.action.Data = e.Item

        Me.action.Operation = If(e.Method = Method.Add, _
                        New RemoveDelegate(AddressOf Me.RemoveItem), _
                        New AddDelegate(AddressOf Me.AddItem))

        Me.action.Method = If(e.Method = Method.Add, _
                     Method.Remove, _
                     Method.Add)

        Return Me.action

    End Function

    ' Raises the "UndoRedo_IsPerformed" Event
    Private Sub Raise_UndoRedo_IsPerformed(ByVal Operation As Operation, _
                                           ByVal Method As Method, _
                                           ByVal Item As ListViewItem)

        RaiseEvent UndoRedo_IsPerformed(Me, New UndoneRedoneEventArgs _
                   With {.Item = Item, _
                         .Method = Method, _
                         .Operation = Operation, _
                         .UndoStack = Me.Undostack, _
                         .RedoStack = Me.Redostack})

        Raise_UndoRedo_StackSizeChanged()

    End Sub

    ' Raises the "UndoRedo_StackSizeChanged" Event
    Private Sub Raise_UndoRedo_StackSizeChanged()

        RaiseEvent UndoRedo_StackSizeChanged(Me, New StackSizeChangedEventArgs _
                   With {.UndoStack = Me.Undostack, _
                         .RedoStack = Me.Redostack, _
                         .UndoStackIsEmpty = Me.Undostack.Count = 0, _
                         .RedoStackIsEmpty = Me.Redostack.Count = 0})

    End Sub

    ' This handles when an Undo or Redo operation is performed.
    Private Sub UndoneRedone(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UndoneRedoneEventArgs) _
    Handles Me.UndoRedo_IsPerformed

        Select Case e.Operation

            Case Operation.Undo
                ' Create a Redo Action for the undone action.
                Me.Redostack.Push(GetReverseAction(e))

            Case Operation.Redo
                ' Create a Undo Action for the redone action.
                Me.Undostack.Push(GetReverseAction(e))

        End Select

    End Sub

    ' Monitors when an Item is added to create an Undo Operation.
    Private Sub OnItemAdded(sender As Object, e As ItemAddedEventArgs) _
    Handles Me.ItemAdded

        If Me.Enable_UndoRedo_Manager _
            AndAlso (Not Me.IsDoingUndo And Not Me.IsDoingRedo) Then

            Me.Redostack.Clear()

            ' // Crate an Undo Action
            Me.action = New ListView_Action
            Me.action.Name = e.Item.Text
            Me.action.Operation = New RemoveDelegate(AddressOf Me.RemoveItem)
            Me.action.Data = e.Item
            Me.action.Method = Method.Remove

            Me.Undostack.Push(action)

            Raise_UndoRedo_StackSizeChanged()

        End If

    End Sub

    ' Monitors when an Item is removed to create an Undo Operation.
    Private Sub OnItemRemoved(sender As Object, e As ItemRemovedEventArgs) _
    Handles Me.ItemRemoved

        If Me.Enable_UndoRedo_Manager _
            AndAlso (Not Me.IsDoingUndo And Not Me.IsDoingRedo) Then

            Me.Redostack.Clear()

            ' // Crate an Undo Action
            Me.action = New ListView_Action
            Me.action.Name = e.Item.Text
            Me.action.Operation = New AddDelegate(AddressOf Me.AddItem)
            Me.action.Data = e.Item
            Me.action.Method = Method.Add

            Me.Undostack.Push(action)

            Raise_UndoRedo_StackSizeChanged()

        End If

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

Comment: want to save some time?  basically forget about ReDo.  it is pretty flawed in this (and the french one).  everytime you push a new UnDo action (create a new control history node), you should empty the ReDo queue.  if you dont, you could try to ReDo a check or text to an item that no longer exists.  For a demo watch the VS UnDo/ReDo buttons.  type 10 garbage lines, then undo * 3.  The ReDo is on and works. When it is on, type another garbage line, it goes off (new history).  Check and text edits can be saved and used into a new history, but seems like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off, since you are starting with a derived class, add these events to it:

```
' (your Item events still lack a Sender and Item to save a lot of work)
Public Event CheckChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
           ByVal lice As ListItemCheckChangedArgs)
Public Shadows Event BeforeLabelEdit(ByVal sender As Object, _
           ByVal oldText As String)
```

BeforeLabelEdit is needed because the basic LV stored the old label text as `Nothing` at the start and you'll want to change that to the .Text property to actually detect a change.  Next, watching for Text changes will require you to do something different than you have for ItemAdded (no matter if it is universal or internal).

When `Before...` fires, store a copy...a Watcher would compare _BeforeText to _AfterText (gotten from watching the normal AfterLabelEdit event) and if they are different, push the _BEforeText onto the stack.

`CheckChanged` is a bit of a cheat.  You can click on a LVItem Check directly and not fire any sort of Enter/GotFocus etc event.  Which means a Watcher cannot get a `_BeforeChecked` value.  The native LV ItemChecked does fire and I just reorganize the args from it to pass what I need to the Watcher (via the above event).  THe lice args:

```
Public Class ListItemCheckChangedArgs
    Public Index As Integer                ' index of item checked
    Public OldValue As CheckState          
    Public NewValue As CheckState

    Public Sub New(ByVal ndx As Integer, ByVal ov As CheckState, _
            ByVal nv As CheckState)
        Index = ndx
        OldValue = ov
        NewValue = nv

    End Sub
End Class
```

The watcher then makes an UnDoAction object with OldValue as the data.  Even without a watcher, this will help capture what you need.

The important part is the Undo class (an internal UM would be different):

```
 Public Class ListViewEUndo
    '... WHO this action applies to
    Friend Ctl As ListViewEX

    ' a listview item, or string (Text) or bool (Check)
    Friend UnDoData As Object

    Friend LVActionType As LVEActionType = LVEActionType.None

    ' original index of items removed / index of item checked
    Friend Index As Integer = -1

  Public Sub New(ByVal _ctl As ListViewEX, ByVal _LvAType As LVEActionType, _
            ByVal _data As Object)
        Ctl = _ctl
        LVActionType = _LvAType
        UnDoData = _data

  End Sub
    ...
```

`LVEActionType` is just AddItem, RemoveItem etc (what this action type is)

You COULD design a base class and then inherit it for a TextUndo, CheckUndo and ItemUndo.  It is a toss up whether that or the resulting short SELECT CASE statements are better.   Finally, there are no DELEGATES because UndoManager class/helpers are going to do apply the changes themselves rather than export the work to the from or control (this ALSO helps to avoid Pushing actions caused by Undo/Redo actions!).

I'm not sure it is a `full code example`, but may help with your issue depending on whether it is internal or not (internal needs almost no events - those are needed mainly to trigger Watcher actions - capture before value, capture/compare After value, respond to Add/RemoveItem etc).